# JavaFX ListView using custom component but with multiple columns?

Tags: java, listview, user-interface, javafx, grid

I was tinkering with the **JFX Library** for a project but I'm unable to render my UI the way I planned.

I was able to make a list view using custom components loaded with `fxml` but it seems like we can't make multiple columns.

**What I have with ListView:**

[image]

**What I want :**

[image]

I also took a look at `TableView` but the cell factory isn't loading my custom controller.

Is there any way around?

Comment: `ListView` does not support this. There's a controlsfx class, [`GridView`](https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/GridView.html), but certain features are missing, e.g. the ability to select items

Comment: You could use a `HBox` as a graphic for the cells of your ListView and place multiple items in it.  I'm not really sure if that is something you want though.  If you only need layout functionality, and not selection and virtual cell technology, there are other options such as a GridPane, FlowPane and TilePane.

Answer (score 0):

Use **TilePane**. I think this is the most correct answer to your question.